# How to interpret だけじゃ with negative verbs?

Tags: meaning, interpretation, negation

I'm confused by the use of だけじゃ in this paragraph:

> たしかに、レスラーの試合があって大会は成り立ってますけどね。でも、やはりあの最高の空間であり、最高の試合っていうものはレスラー**だけじゃ**作れないですから。と、ボクは思ってますからね。ボクが思ってることが正しいか、正しくないかはわからないけど、ボクはそう思ってますから。で、先ほども言いましたけど、口に出さないと何も伝わらないですから。『ありがとう』って思ってる**だけじゃ**、誰にも何も伝わらないですから。なので、素直の気持ちを昨日リング上で言わせていただきました」

In this first sentence:

> やはりあの最高の空間であり、最高の試合っていうものはレスラー**だけじゃ**作れないですから

It should be saying something like "Wrestlers alone can't produce great matches" but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

And in this second one:

> 『ありがとう』って思ってる**だけじゃ**、誰にも何も伝わらないですから。なので、素直の気持ちを昨日リング上で言わせていただきました」

It should be saying something like "I felt grateful and needed to say so" but it looks like he's saying "I don't want to say nothing to no one". So. that part 誰にも何も伝わらない is really confusing.

Comment: I think if you change "no one" to "anyone", it makes easier to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix it into the affirmative form.

「ありがとう」と思ってるだけ**で**、誰にでも何でも伝わる: Only with thinking "thank you", whatever can penetrate to whomever. (Here, this で is instrumental case and means cause or condition.)

When you change it to the negation form, it's ありがとうと思ってるだけで**は**、誰にも何も伝わらない: You can't tell anything to anyone only with thinking "thank you". (This は means that the condition of thinking "thank you" is not a sufficient condition for nothing being penetrable.)

With では contracted, it becomes the same as the example sentence. So, it means "you can't tell anything to anyone just because you secretly thank people".

Comment: Would you mind if asked you affirmative form of "誰にも何も伝わらない". I thought that negating "誰にも何も伝わらない" becomes ”誰か一人ぐらいには何か伝わる。”. Because "誰にも何も伝わらない" implies "誰一人として理解しない".　Then negate this, it becomes ”少なくとも誰か一人くらい理解する”. Therefore, 誰か一人ぐらいには何か伝わる。

Comment: @kimi I didn't negate the example sentence, instead, brought an affirmative sentence whose negation corresponds with the example sentence. To begin with it depends what part is negated.

Comment: At first, you had already assumed "Let's fix it into the affirmative form." I think if you negate whatever can penetrate to whomever, it becomes whatever can not penetrate to whomever. I interpret that if you pick up not any persons but some people are willing to hear, now you can find the whatever can penetrate to some people.

Comment: @kimi  I avoided directly using "let's negate it" or so, instead, used "affirmative form" or "negation form" because I wanted to avoid what you point out. In that sense, it was not correct that I commented "whose negation corresponds with".

Comment: I am afraid I am taking your time. But I can't understand the meaning of your sentence "the condition of thinking "thank you" is not a sufficient condition for nothing being penetrable."  and I can't find it corresponds to "You can't tell anything to anyone only with thinking "thank you". I think  "the condition of "secretly" thinking "thank you" is "a" sufficient condition for nothing being penetrable."

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence,　だけじゃ　means だけじゃ不十分　not good enough.

やはりあの最高の空間であり、最高の試合っていうものはレスラーだけじゃ作れないですから.

The wrestlers are not good enough to produce a great match and great atmosphere.

誰にも何も伝わらない looks multiple negations.

But I think that single negative, it means

anyone 誰でも

anything 何でも

I can't tell 伝わらない

using anyone in a negative sentence. I can't tell anything. 何も伝えられない。

using anybody in a negative sentence. Don't tell this to anyone.　誰にも伝えないで。

Then,
I can't tell anything to anyone. 誰にも何も伝わらない

『ありがとう』って思ってるだけじゃ、誰にも何も伝わらないですから.

Just feeling grateful is not good enough. Just feeling grateful does not tell anything to anyone.

Comment: Is じゃ a contraction of じゃない or is it just a filler?

Comment: I think it usually is a contraction of じゃない. But not so sure.